# Can I mount and local repartition / encryption to the nbd?

Tags: encryption, nbd

I am looking for a way to mount a network disk and encrypt it on my local PC, in the way that the server won't be able to know the content of my files.

After searching I found nbd, a way to mount a block device over the network. I can't, however, find anything about locally partitioning it, or using local encryption. I just would like to use it like any other disk!

Is it possible to encrypt it locally?

Comment: At first, you said that you want to mount network disk and then you said you found a way to mount block device over the network. Could you clarify what resources do you have available? (samba share, nfs share, iscsi target, something else)

Comment: You can use it like any other block device, that's kind of the point. The main problem is getting the server to export the nbd in the first place. And how to optimize network traffic... and how to deal with filesystem corruption on disconnects and the like.

Comment: @mrc02_kr https://packages.debian.org/buster/nbd-server https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device

frostschutz Ahhh, that sounds like a problem. I actually just wanted to use it as a mountable device that I would sendrsync backups too. I could probably also abuse nextcloud for this, but my preferences are to have a block device.